# Non maxima suppression in Python gives bad result: what is wrong?

Tags: python, image-processing, edge-detection, canny-operator

I am implementing Canny edgedetection myself in Python, and I am stuck at the non maxima suppression part. I thought I had the code right, but I get a really bad outcome with no pretty lines at all. I used the Canny edge detection by Skimage to compare, and below is the result (left: magnitude of the gradient by Sobel filters, middle: after non maxima suppression, right: result of skimage Canny (and I know this is after thresholding and hysteresis, but I expect that the results after non maxima suppression should be comparable to the skimage Canny outcome)).

[image]

Here is the code I used for the non maxima suppression:

```
def non_max_sup8(magn,direct):
    size=magn.shape
    out=np.zeros_like(magn)

    direct=np.rad2deg(direct)+180 # direction is now between 0 and 360

    for i in range(1,size[0]-1):
        for j in range(1,size[1]-1):

            if 0<=direct[i,j]<22.5 or 337.5<=direct[i,j]<=360 or 157.5<=direct[i,j]<202.5:
                before=magn[i,j-1] # compare to left and right
                after=magn[i,j+1]

            elif 22.5<=direct[i,j]<67.5 or 202.5<=direct[i,j]<247.5:
                before=magn[i+1,j-1] # compare diagonally
                after=magn[i-1,j+1]

            elif 67.5<=direct[i,j]<112.5 or 247.5<=direct[i,j]<292.5:
                before=magn[i+1,j] # compare above and under
                after=magn[i-1,j]

            else:
                before=magn[i-1,j-1] # compare diagonally
                after=magn[i+1,j+1]

            if magn[i,j]>=before and magn[i,j]>=after:
                out[i,j]=magn[i,j]
    return out
```

The gradients are calculated as follows and should be right. (The direction is in radians between -pi and pi and are in the code above transformed to 0 to 360 degrees)

```
def edges(img,filterv=vSobel,filterh=hSobel):
    height,width = img.shape
    magn=np.zeros_like(img)
    direc=np.zeros_like(img)
    X=np.zeros_like(img)
    Y=np.zeros_like(img) 

    for y in range(3,height-2):
        for x in range(3,width-2):
            box = img[x-1:x+2,y-1:y+2]

            transformv = filterv * box
            Gy = transformv.sum()/4

            transformh = filterh * box
            Gx = transformh.sum()/4

            X[x,y] = Gx 
            Y[x,y] = Gy
            magn[x,y]=np.sqrt(Gx**2+Gy**2)
            direc[x,y]=np.arctan2(Gy,Gx)
    return X,Y,magn,direc
```

So, my question is: what am I doing wrong? I am thinking the following, but I would like to hear your thoughts:
Suppose the direction is 90degrees (so upwards), then I thought you actually want to compare to the pixel right and left instead of below and above (as I did up till now), since then you get a single pixel edge. However I based my code on things I found on the internet and they seem to all do something like above: comparing to the pixels in the gradient direction instead of in the normal direction. What do you think about this? Am I misunderstanding something, or is my idea not so bad?

EDIT: trying the above (comparing the pixel with the two pixels in the normal direction, instead of the direction of the pixel) gives a result similar to the canny edge detection of the skimage.

Regards.

Comment: `Gx = transformv` looks wrong. The "v" is for vertical, no? And the "x" is horizontal, no? Your result is consistent with a 90 degree rotation of the directions. I recommend that you plot and examine the direction image and compare that with your expectation according to the edges in the image.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I did not even notice. However curiously I also swapped the Sobel filters, so the `filterv` was actually the filter used to compute Gx, so that it cancels the mistake out haha! I will change it in my question :)

Comment: Still, look at the values of `direct`, to make sure they match your expectations. You might have to use `-direct` or `direct+90` or `90-direct` or some such transformation to make the angles match the direction **across** the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Order of 45 and 135 is wrong(changed) because you consider **xy** coordinate system when you **should work** with **yx** coordinate systems(45 degrees in yx is equivalent to 315 degrees in xy plane). Based on my implementation, it should be:

```
#for 45
elif 22.5<=direct[i,j]<67.5 or 202.5<=direct[i,j]<247.5:
   before=magn[i-1,j-1]
   after=magn[i+1,j+1]

#for 135
else:
   before=magn[i+1,j-1]
   after=magn[i-1,j+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments that have already been made I'd like to say that the Canny Edge Detection implementation of Skimage includes an interpolation step for the non-maximum-suppression task which your implementation (and some others freely available in the web) is missing. I've made the experience that results are way better when doing the interpolation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).